# How do I have VoiceOver read two adjacent Labels as one with a pause?

Tags: ios, voiceover

**Original Problem:** Two-Line Label that is read as one-continuous string without pause.

[image]

**Goal:** Separate each line with a pause (as if there's a hyphen between them). 
**One Solution:** Separate two lines into two adjacent labels; read as one with pause.

Here's the two scenarios.  The left text (original) is one label vs the right text being two labels within a vertical stack.

[image]

The left set of text is read as a continuous string without a pause (unless I put a hyphen between them).

So I'm thinking of having two labels that look like the single set on the left (there's now a gap between the two labels which I have to fix).

I thought about putting the two labels within an array.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        accessibilityElements = [line1label!, line2Label!]
 }
```

**Question:** I'm getting lost here.  
What is the best way of reading two two strings of text as a single unit with a pause between them (as if reading two sentences vs a single string)?

Comment: Maybe a newline \n character?

Comment: This is for client with a two-line label without punctuation.  I found that either a hyphen '-' or a period '.' would do it.  So It's a small price to pay to add a period after each sentence.  Best not to over-engineer this.

Comment: Sounds like you answered your own question.  Punctuation causes the screen reader to pause for a micro second, just like you do when reading multiple sentences with punctuation between them, whether a period, comma, semi-colon, etc.  Keep in mind, though, that the screen reader user can adjust the punctuation setting on their screen reader and might actually hear "period" or "comma" if you add those characters.  In general, whatever looks correct grammatically is what you should use.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to set the label's `accessibilityLabel` property separate from its text property. VoiceOver will speak the contents of the `accessibilityLabel` instead of the text. If the view's `accessibilityLabel` is nil, it will attempt to speak the text. Using the `accessibilityLabel` you can have the VoiceOver string be different than the display string.

So, in your single label example, set the label text to "Order 1-2 titles: $19.99 each. Order 3-12 titles: $14.99 each". With a period between the two lines, VoiceOver will pause between them. A comma should give a slightly shorter pause.

You could use code like this:

```
let lines = ["Order 1-2 titles: $19.99 each","order 312 titles: $14.99 each"]
// Combine the lines with a space between for the label text
labelView.text = lines.joined(separator:" ") 
// Combine the lines with a comma between so VoiceOver pasues between
labelView.accessibilityLabel = lines.joined(separator: ", ")
```

### Edit (July 2023):

Another option is to group multiple items into a parent view, and then set the `accessibilityElements` of the parent view to hold the child elements. That will cause the system to make the parent view the item that is selectable in VO, and read the accessibility strings for all of the `accessibilityElements` concatenated together. You will probably want periods or commas at the ends of the individual accessibility labels so that VO pauses between items as you desire.